# Coldfusion how to disable sql-mode 'only_full_group_by" in cfquery

Tags: mysql, group-by, coldfusion

In a ColdFusion application I have a query with several joins and I need one MAX number from one of the tables.  I am getting all tangled up in 'only_full_group_by'.  I cannot disable it in etc or in the Administrator, because I am on a shared system and have no access to those.  I'd like to disable it at run time.  Here's a simplified version of the query:

```
<cfquery name = 'test' datasource = 'whatever'> 
select  PersActExt,PersActPaid,PersActMdate,PersActbl,
   PersTrId,PersTrMas,PersTrSub,PersTrCode,
   MAX(PersTrPaid),  MAX(PersTrDate)
  from PersActiv          
      left join PersTrans on
           PersTrId = PersActId and
           PersTrMas = PersActMas and
           PersTrSub = PersActSub and
           PersTrCode = PersActCode
  where PersActMas = 'bill'
  group by PersTrId,PersTrMas,PersTrSub,PersTrCode
  </cfquery>
```

The fact is the condition PersActMas = 'bill' reduces this to one record per Person in the PersAct table.  I suppose I could put a MAX on all those Persact type fields, but there are other tables that also have to be joined in; and frankly I don't want a MAX on everything just to pick up one Max number in PersTr.

Is there a way to disable the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode within the query?  Or better yet within the application?  Or can anyone suggest another way around this problem.  I know I can split this up into several queries and then stitch everything back together in ColdFusion, but that's a lot of code to get around this bad MySql mode.

Comment: @BillKarwin, well Bill, people keep saying this, but I believe my code is entirely correct without the only-full-group-by.By making it impossible to disable this when we know what we are doing, they diminish the power of SQL; in exchange for this we get to know that it is a smidge more idiot proof than it was before.  I'm not convinced this is a good trade off.

Comment: For the sample query, would changing `where` to `and` help?

Comment: Do the strategies in the docs not work? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting. What happens if you add the rest of the columns you are not aggregating on into the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @DanBracuk I'd like to try changing where to and but I'm not sure how I do it?  Do you mean to add it to the join on line?

Comment: @AdamCameron I don't see any "strategies" in the docs. Because I am using a shared online system I can't change any sql variables globally, but was hoping to find a temporary run-time fix.  I suspect that putting all the non-aggregate columns in the group-by would do it, but there are dozens of them.

Comment: @BillKarwin -- my local mysql which I use for development is showing version 5.7.33.  I don't know what is being used on the production system which is on a shared server.

Comment: @BettyMock, SELECT @@VERSION; will tell you the version that the server is.

Comment: Yes @BettyMock, I mean moving the filter on `PersActMas = 'bill'` from the `where clause` to the `join`.

Comment: @DanBracuk, Yes Dan I tried it that way, and the result was that the condition did not operate at all, and I got records that did not satisfy PersActMas = 'memb-bill'.    Not sure why that would happen, but possibly the "on" process is a little different from the "where" process.

Comment: @BillKarwin, Hi Bill, I to the version for my development machine using the Linux command line.  But the production version runs from cPanel, and I haven't researched whether or how that will tell me the version.

Comment: What I am really asking here is whether there is a run-time way to override that mode in ColdFusion.

Comment: "override the mode in ColdFusion" doesn't make any sense. It's a DB setting: nothing to do with CF. However how to change the MySQL setting @ runtime is clearly explained in the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting. Did you read the docs? Did you try what it suggests?

Comment: @AdamCameron Yes I did read the docs.  It doesn't help because my production system is on cpanel and I accessing mysql is a different step from running ColdFusion.

Comment: @BillKarwin primary keys for PersAct are PersActId, PersActMas,PersActSub,PersActCode.  Primary keys for PersTr are PersTrId,PersTrMas,PersTrSub,PersTrCode,PersTrSeq.  The first four keys of each table are the same, which explains my join statement.  As far as I can tell MySql is not in fact going by dependencies, despite saying that, but going only by the field names.

Comment: @AdamCameron.  Since I have a cfquery facility in ColdFusion, I hoped to put a set sql-mode within such a query.  If I put it in the query which contains the select it appears to be ignored.  I'm wondering whether putting it in a separate query would be effective, but haven't tried that yet.  The whole thing is a great pain.  I've spent probably 6 hours coding around this, and it's working fine, but seems like a lot of extra work because of this decision by the mysql developers.

Comment: @AdamCameron  I'm used to a system where if there is an aggregated field and some fields are not aggregated, the first or last value of that the non-aggregated field is automatically used.  And no crap about refusing to execute the code or yammering about dependencies (which mysql doesn't seem to be getting right anyway).  If someone doesn't like getting the first or last non-aggregated value they can code to get what they want.

Comment: @BettyMock it's impossible to comment on what you have tried/not tried if all you give us is "I tried x". _Show us_. Update yer question to say "I tried doing this in `<cfquery>` and it didn't work [show the code] etc. And if like you've tried stuff and then include it in the question, it saves us looking in to [that very approach] and suggesting it. I get you can't admin yer own prod MySQL server, but can you not raise a ticket with them and say "turn this setting off pls?"

Comment: I doubt - given how tied down yer prod env sounds - you'd be able to change that setting globally via a statement from CF, but you could try: nothing ventured nothing gained 'n'all. Same with the session one (although I suspect the setting might only kick in when the connection is first made? Try it and see). @dpolehonski as given the answer for doing it ad hoc, but will depend on whether your JDBC connection has `allowMultiQueries` set to `true`. If you do try and it dun't work, pls update the question accordingly with what you've tried...

Answer (score 1):

Thinking laterally about the problem, could you restructure your query to join the PersAct table to a pre-aggregated subquery? This removes the need to perform a grouping on the outer query and running up against the limitation of your setup.

```
SELECT
  PersActExt,
  PersActPaid,
  PersActMdate,
  PersActbl,
  PersTrId,
  PersTrMas,
  PersTrSub,
  PersTrCode,
  MaxPersTrPaid,
  MaxPersTrDate
FROM
  PersActiv          
LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      PersTrId,
      PersTrMas,
      PersTrSub,
      PersTrCode,
      MAX(PersTrPaid) AS MaxPersTrPaid,
      MAX(PersTrDate) AS MaxPersTrDate
    FROM
      PersTrans
    GROUP BY
      PersTrId,
      PersTrMas,
      PersTrSub,
      PersTrCode
  ) AS PersTr ON
    PersTrId = PersActId and
    PersTrMas = PersActMas and
    PersTrSub = PersActSub and
    PersTrCode = PersActCode
WHERE PersActMas = 'bill'
```

Edit:
For those wanting to know how to remove the 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' on an ad hoc basis, you need to add the below snippet to your query.

SET SESSION sql_mode = sys.list_drop(@@session.sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY');

This will only work if the DB user used in ColdFusion has the correct permissions *and* the option to allow multiple queries in a cfquery call is set.

Comment: I might separate these out into two answers as it kinda is, and will probably garner different degrees of upvote / feeedback. Good answer that said ;-)

Comment: Dpolehonski - I will certainly try this, even though I already split it into two queries and assorted baggage.  I had fooled around with a subquery, with no good results.  This looks very promising and also illuminates how mysql might be viewing "dependencies".

Comment: Dpolehonski  -- I will also try the ad hoc removal of only-full-group-by.  I don't have control over the ColdFusion settings on my production system, but wondering if a cftransaction might allow me to do this in two queries.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @AdamCameron -- thank you for your suggestions about showing my code on what didn't work -- I'll do that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Tested the query on MySQL 5.7 here: https://dbfiddle.uk/E1em1_k2

I tested with your query, with the last line as you wrote it:

```
...
group by PersTrId,PersTrMas,PersTrSub,PersTrCode;
```

This resulted in the error due to the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY:

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.PersActiv.PersActExt' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Then I tested with an alternative last line:

```
...
group by PersActId,PersActMas,PersActSub,PersActCode;
```

This works with the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY at the default value. See the demo for proof. Note that I had to do my alternative query first, because the dbfiddle aborts when it gets an error.

The reason is that MySQL 5.7 introduced the capability to infer functional dependencies when using GROUP BY on the primary key.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

> SQL:1999 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301 if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns: If such a relationship exists between name and custid, the query is legal. This would be the case, for example, were custid a primary key of customers.
>
> MySQL 5.7.5 and later implements detection of functional dependence.

Since the four columns in the GROUP BY are in fact the primary key of the `PersActive` table, MySQL can tell that other columns of that table are guaranteed to have one value per grouping.

There are multiple rows in PersTrans, but the functional dependencies are still analyzed, so the columns that are known to be equal to primary key columns of PersActiv are still okay to use in the query without aggregation. The other columns of PersTrans that are not functionally dependent are already in MAX() expressions in your query, which also satisfies the requirement.

I conclude that functional dependency analysis works in MySQL 5.7, and this would be an effective workaround in the case you show.

You wrote:

> I'm used to a system where if there is an aggregated field and some fields are not aggregated, the first or last value of that the non-aggregated field is automatically used.

In my experience, this includes only MySQL prior to 5.7, or SQLite. It's illegitimate in the ANSI/ISO SQL standard, and other SQL implementations conform to the standard.

MySQL 5.7 does not have a "bad sql mode" — it has been *corrected* to enforce the rule per the SQL standard, like most other brands of SQL also do.

Back to your original question:

> Is there a way to disable the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode within the query? Or better yet within the application?

You can change the sql mode globally, either in the `my.cnf` options file, or using `SET GLOBAL sql_mode='...';`. I would do both, because if you change options dynamically with `SET GLOBAL`, they are reset to whatever is in the options file the next time you restart the MySQL Server.

You can also change the sql mode in a session with `SET SESSION sql_mode='...';` and it takes effect for the remainder of the current session. But `SET SESSION` is a separate statement that you would have to execute in the session prior to your query. It can't be combined with a query.

There is an option in MySQL 8.0 to use [the "hint" syntax to set certain options for the scope of a single SQL query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-set-var). But in your case, you're using MySQL 5.7, so you'd have to upgrade to get this feature.

A similar feature exists in Percona Server 5.6 and later to [set a variable for one statement](https://www.percona.com/blog/using-per-query-variable-statements-in-percona-server/). This does not apply if you use stock MySQL. You'd have to use the Percona branch of MySQL.

Regardless, I recommend you do not change the sql mode. It's proper that it behaves the way it does, because it prevents queries that may inadvertently produce wrong results.

Comment: Just because someone set a standard doesn't mean it is optimal.  It means that's what the committee thought at that time.  I believe I am quite experienced enough to disagree with whatever committee that may be.

Comment: Bless your heart.

Comment: Bill, thanks for the kindly reply.  Perhaps you could explain something to me.  Why does mysql recognize the dependence of the aggregated fields on the persact keys, but not on the perstr keys which are identical and located in the same table as the aggregated fields?  I realize it has something to do with the way the join works, but I find it at the least unintuitive, and at worst wrong.

Comment: The four columns are the primary key of the PersAct table, and by grouping by those columns, there is a logical inference that there can be only one row in PersAct in each grouping. Therefore, there can be only one value for each of the other columns of PersAct. Whereas the PersTr table has a five-column PK, so grouping by the same four columns it is not inferrable that there can be only one row per group. So there can be multiple values in other columns of PersTr.

Comment: But in fact, the extra key in PersTr is exactly why I had to use an aggregator.  If there is no extra key, no aggregation is required.  So it seems to me that grouping for the four columns in PersTr would definitely imply that the aggregation is to be over the last key.  In fact it could not mean anything else whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But if your group by names a subset of the PK columns, then _any_ of the columns might have multiple values per group, so MySQL insists on the single-value rule, and you have to put PersTr columns within aggregate functions to make them unambiguous. Whereas if you group by _all_ four columns of the PersAct table, then there can only be one value in each of those columns per group. Since the respective columns of PersTr are bound to be equal, then those also have one value per group.

Comment: Will have to ponder on this.  It is not the way I think of the logic.  thanks for your comments.

Comment: Okay, when there is no join mysql accepts the four perstr keys in the group by, and properly aggregates the fields I request.  So it knows perfectly well that an aggregation is over multiple records -- otherwise no aggregation is required.  when I put in the join from persact, suddenly mysql doesn't know this anymore?  I don't get it?

Comment: You're still grouping by columns from PersTr?

Comment: Obviously I can't use what doesn't work whether I agree with the logic or not.  I long ago split this into two queries, one of which involves persact and has no aggregations, and the other of which involved perstr and does the aggregations.  I dump the whole thing into a table which combines it all.  However, if I have to do this again I'll use the keys from the higher level table.

Comment: Re your previous comment  "if your group by names a subset of the PK columns, then any of the columns might have multiple values per group"  -- this is not so.  There are five columns in the primary key for perstr.  If I group by four of them, there can be multiple values only for the combo of four.  I don't see any way there could be multiple values for one of the keys and not the others.  In fact, the only key for which where can be multiple values is PersTrSeq, which is what distinguishes rows sharing the first 4 keys.

Comment: Have you looked at the demo I linked to? It uses join, so you don't have to split the query. https://dbfiddle.uk/E1em1_k2

Comment: Yes, your demo makes it much clearer.  Thank you.

Comment: Now that it is much clearer, what I see is that when I use a join mysql completely loses track of the original dependencies in each table and regards the entire thing as one amorphous table, in which anything which is not in the group-by is automatically not dependent on the group-by, and thus must be indicated as aggregated.  Otherwise we get our error. In order to use the join as I need it, involving about 5 different tables, I would have to put an aggregation on many, many fields, since mysql has no idea whatever what they are actually dependent on.

Comment: This arrangement is very cumbersome and forces a lot of extra code which would not be necessary if mysql maintained its knowledge of the original dependencies; not to mention completely confusing lots of people who are in fact decent coders and wasting their time.  It is not backwards compatible meaning it will break many systems incurring the expense, aggravation and reputational hit of tracking down and fixing  the problem.  This can be substantial. The ability to shut off this "feature" depends on access to the mysql system, so those of us on a shared system cannot do that.

Comment: All this in service of preventing people from making coding errors.  Here's a fact; bad coders will write bad code, no matter what you do.   If any of my employees had implemented something this poorly I would have made them rewrite it .  If that happened several times they would no longer be my employee.  I have not been a fan of sql anyway, and it is this kind of thing which causes my low opinion.

Comment: I really, really hope you stop using SQL.

Comment: Oh Bill, I would if I could.  But what is the alternative?

Comment: @BettyMock There are many NoSQL alternatives that have gradually been growing in popularity over the last 15 years or so. https://hostingdata.co.uk/nosql-database/

Comment: Bill, thanks so much.  I will definitely look into this.  I hope you are not too pissed off with me, as I value the information you have provided on some of my other questions.